# I want to rename a file with Regex concept

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I want to rename a file "TF-ICOT160017_JATS.xml" to "TF-ICOT160017.xml". Kindly check below program and provide the correct Batch program for this concept.

```
@echo off
set /p file=Enter File Path: 
:Main
echo.
echo 1. Rename
echo 2. Exit
echo.
set /p choice=Enter Your choice: 
IF %choice% == 1 goto File_Rename
IF %choice% == 2 exit
:File_Rename
ren TF-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_JATS.xml TF-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml
goto Main
```

Comment: I suggest to use file manager Total Commander (shareware) which has built-in a multi-rename feature which supports Perl regular expressions for renaming files and folders. And the big advantage is that you can see how the selected files (or folders) would be renamed with whatever you have configured without any programming skills before rename is done. Total Commander shows the expected result after every modification of the rename parameters immediately in the files/folders list below the rename parameters for verification by the user. And Total Commander can even undo the renames once done.

Comment: @dbenham created a really cool hybrid [script](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) for renaming files with regular explression.

Comment: Regardless of all the previous answers and suggestions, if your file names all conform to that same format it would be easy enough to use the `SET` command substring function or the `FOR /F` command to split apart the file name using the underscore as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a single command line can be used for this file rename operation:

```
ren TF-??????????_JATS.xml TF-??????????.xml
```

One more hint:

Don't use `set /P` for letting the user choose between two options. The user can just hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without entering anything at all accidentally and your batch file exits with a syntax error. The user has also the freedom to enter anything else than 1 or 2 and your batch file fails again.

Use the command **CHOICE**. Open a command prompt window and run `choice /?` for help on this command.

```
@echo off
:Main
echo/
echo 1. Rename
echo 2. Exit
echo/
choice /C12 /N "Please make your choice: "
if errorlevel 2 exit /B
ren TF-??????????_JATS.xml TF-??????????.xml
goto Main
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: I know there is a caveat to using the question mark for renaming.  It is not always bullet proof.  Trying to find that link again.  I just posted it a few weeks ago on another forum or maybe it was here.